# Converting Integer to byte array in java giving a diff value

Tags: java

- Im trying to convert an integer of size 4 to byte array but its
  giving me strange value.

  ```
   byte[] bytes1 = my_int_to_bb_le(196,4);
     public static  byte[] my_int_to_bb_le(int myInteger,int length)
     {
       return ByteBuffer.allocate(length).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(myInteger).array();
     }
  ```
- output : 
  -60 0 0 0
- required output as : 196 0 0 0

  Tried the alternate this code but not working as its giving the same
  output

  ```
  public static byte[] convertIntByteArray(int intval,int len)     
  {       
     byte[] intarray = new byte[len];          

     for(int i=0;i<len;i++)        
     {
         if(i==0)
         {
             intarray[i]=(byte)intval;
         }
         else
             intarray[i]=0;        
      } 
      return intarray;     
  }
  ```
- output : -60 0 0 0
- required output as : 196 0 0 0

  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because, a (signed) byte is between `-128 to 127`

```
public class TestNumber{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    byte b1 = -60;
    int b2 = b1 & 0xFF;
    System.out.println("Without casting "+ b1);
    System.out.println("With casting "+b2);
    System.out.println("Bitwise Trickery " + (b1 & 0xFF));
  }
}
```

If you want to look at how bits are arranged in the memory for each number, just use the `calc.exe` supplied with all Windows OS, change the `view` to `Programmer` and then, just enter a number and see its bitwise values. That's what I use all the time for bitwise operations :-)

Comment: so is there any way i can get rid of this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the unsigned representation of the byte with:

```
for( byte b : byteArray ) {
    System.out.print((b & 0xFF )+" ");
}
```

But more commonly bytes are printed as zero-padded hexadecimals for a much more comfortable viewing format:

```
for( byte b : byteArray ) {
    System.out.format("%02X ", b);
}
```

Comment: or you could just do this: `System.out.println(b & 0xFF);`